# plpgsql syntax error when assigning CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to TIMESTAMP field

Tags: timestamp, syntax-error, plpgsql

I need a trigger to update a field with the exact date and time when the record is deleted. The fecha_validez_hasta field is TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE. I get a syntax error.

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE '||TG_RELNAME||'_hv SET fecha_validez_hasta='||CURRENT_TIMESTAMP||' where id='||OLD.id;
```

[image]

The error is given in the beginning of the time section. It looks like it doesn't recognize it as a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement converts the value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` into a string, which is not what you want.

Make the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function call part of the real statement:

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE '||TG_RELNAME||'_hv SET fecha_validez_hasta=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where id='||OLD.id
```

Note `fecha_validez_hasta=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `fecha_validez_hasta='||CURRENT_TIMESTAMP||'..`